# Can't access any method of formData object in React Native, except append

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, form-data

I'm trying to run the following code in react native(Expo):

```js
import FormData from "form-data"; // installed with npm install 'form-data'

const formData = new FormData();

console.log(formData.getHeaders());    <------- formData.getHeaders is not a function. (In 'formData.getHeaders()', 'formData.getHeaders' is undefined)
```

But the only method that works is `append`.

`getHeaders()` works if I run the above code with `node`, but doesn't work in react native app.

Why doesn't it recognize the FormData methods such as `getHeaders()` or `getBoundary()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to a bug in axios version 0.25.0 https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4406.
It's now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to replace the import line with this

```
import * as FormData from "form-data";

const formData = new FormData();


console.log(formData.getHeaders());
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample usage? I still get the same error using `const FormData = new FormData.default()`

Comment: I updated , there is no default exported from the library itself , so all you need is to import all exported as FormData

Comment: I get this error: `TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new FormData()')`